# Как хранить маршруты в базе MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

Никогда не сталкивался с логистикой, только в теории в институте.
Представьте себе множество точек соединенных линиями. Точки БЕЗ координат(x,y,z). У точек есть названия - это пункты выгрузки, загрузки, а линии их соединяющие -  это машруты. Чтобы проложить маршрут необходимо задать начальный пункт и конечный. А программа уже выдает количество промежуточных пунктов и их названия.
Вот пример : [Карта с точками](http://evemaps.dotlan.net/route/2:Jita:Litiura)

А вопрос как правильно мне хранить эти отношения в базе данных, чтобы я мог эффективно прокладывать маршрут и иметь представление о колчиестве пересекаемых пунктов?

Я склоняюсь к методу что необходимо в первую очередь создать таблицу уникальных названий точек с id PRYMARY AUTO_INCREMENT

Затем сделать что то вроде

```
SELECT t1.`name`,t2.`name` AS `second_name` FROM `table` t1 FULL JOIN `table` t2 ON t1.`name`!=t2.`name`
```

и проверить есть ли между ними связь, если есть, то записать в таблицу многие ко многим (пару, как их id в пару столбцов)

Либо пойти по другому пути и проверить сколько между ними точек и определить их id

Первый способ гибкий, поскольку можно будет выбирать маршруты. А второй более быстрый - дает однозначный вариант и считать ничего не нужно будет, только вот если понадобятся не линейные маршруты а с заездами в соседние - то тут я не знаю тоже какая то формула понадобится.

В первом же случае мне придется выстраивать два дерева сцепленными ветвями, где их основания начальная и конечная точка, все сцепленные ветки это пути, а самый короткий путь - это искомый.

Если кто сталкивался с такого рода задачами - подскажите где искать информацию.

Спасибо.

Comment: Ненаправленный граф. Матрица смежности. Поиск (кратчайшего) пути. По-моему, терминов для поиска достаточно. Если нет - меня дополнят. PS. Вообще-то не для SQL задачка, хотя и на нём вполне решаема. И даже порой достаточно эффективно.

Comment: Акина - спасибо. Полез изучать если удастся найти решение выложу его здесь. Кстати сюда вполне вписывается схема метрополитена там тоже есть точки и линии их соединяющие. Задачка из разряда сколько надо проехать станций от одной точки до другой.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo4j

Comment: @Mcile Метрополитен немного не из той оперы. Там есть транзитные узлы. И пересадка - достаточно дорогая операция.